# Calculate total duration using timestamp

Tags: python, sqlite

In my SQLite table I have the following fields (`timestamp`, `zone_id`, `object_count` and `object_ids`) and these are data of people queueing up in a zone. Whenever a person joins the queue, he is captured by sensors and is assigned an `object_id`. `timestamp` is data sent from the sensors server into the database every second.

I would need to find the duration of each `object_ids` in the queue to compute and display the wait time in my web app using a flask framework. For example, `object_ids` (2166) enters the queue at `2020-10-19 17:03:46.000000` and leaves at `2020-10-19 17:03:50.000000`, and his queue time is 5 seconds. Simple logic would be to subtract the timestamp when the `object_id` first appears from the timestamp where the `object_id` last appears.

```
#       timestamp           zone_id   object_count      object_ids #  

2020-10-19 17:03:43.000000    10           2         ['2140', '2143']
2020-10-19 17:03:44.000000    10           2         ['2140', '2143']
2020-10-19 17:03:45.000000    10           2         ['2140', '2143']
2020-10-19 17:03:46.000000    10           3         ['2140', '2143', '2166']
2020-10-19 17:03:47.000000    10           3         ['2140', '2143', '2166']
2020-10-19 17:03:49.000000    10           3         ['2140', '2143', '2166']
2020-10-19 17:03:50.000000    10           3         ['2140', '2143', '2166']
2020-10-19 17:03:51.000000    10           2         ['2140', '2143']
2020-10-19 17:03:53.000000    10           2         ['2140', '2143']
```

How can I query and solve this?

Comment: What exactly was the difficulty you encountered when doing this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am new to sqlite syntax and am not sure of the right way to code it out. Would appreciate if someone could point me the right way to do so.

Comment: Here the right way is shown: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: What is the data type of object_ids?

Comment: @forpas data type for  object_ids is string.

Comment: It looks like json. Why do you enclose them in brackets? Also do you have another table like a users table where all these objectids are defined?

Comment: @forpas The raw data imported from the sensor server is in json format. It is then converted to a dict before inserting into the database. Yes i have another object table for the objectids but it mainly contains other information such as its position/size/velocity etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your table's name is `queues` and the table where the `object_id`s are defined is `objects` (change the names to the actual ones), so you have something like this:

```
CREATE table objects (`object_id` TEXT);
INSERT INTO objects (`object_id`) VALUES
  ('2140'), ('2143'), ('2166');

CREATE TABLE queues (`timestamp` TEXT, `zone_id` INTEGER, `object_count` INTEGER, `object_ids` VARCHAR(24));
INSERT INTO queues (`timestamp`, `zone_id`, `object_count`, `object_ids`) VALUES
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:43.000000', '10', '2', '[''2140'', ''2143'']'),
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:44.000000', '10', '2', '[''2140'', ''2143'']'),
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:45.000000', '10', '2', '[''2140'', ''2143'']'),
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:46.000000', '10', '3', '[''2140'', ''2143'', ''2166'']'),
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:47.000000', '10', '3', '[''2140'', ''2143'', ''2166'']'),
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:49.000000', '10', '3', '[''2140'', ''2143'', ''2166'']'),
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:50.000000', '10', '3', '[''2140'', ''2143'', ''2166'']'),
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:51.000000', '10', '2', '[''2140'', ''2143'']'),
  ('2020-10-19 17:03:53.000000', '10', '2', '[''2140'', ''2143'']');
```

you can get the results that you want with an SQLite query that joins the 2 tables, by using window functions `MIN()` and `MAX()` and the function `strftime()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.object_id,
       strftime('%s', MAX(q.timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY o.object_id)) - 
       strftime('%s', MIN(q.timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY o.object_id)) diff
FROM objects o INNER JOIN queues q
ON ',' || REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(q.object_ids, '''', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''), ' ', '') || ','
LIKE '%,' || o.object_id || ',%'
```

If your version of SQLite does not support window functions use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT o.object_id,
       strftime('%s', MAX(q.timestamp)) - strftime('%s', MIN(q.timestamp)) diff
FROM objects o INNER JOIN queues q
ON ',' || REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(q.object_ids, '''', ''), '[', ''), ']', ''), ' ', '') || ','
LIKE '%,' || o.object_id || ',%'
GROUP BY o.object_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2f5e91f16ec69442e49b185da43eb13c).
Results:

```
> object_id | diff
> :-------- | ---:
> 2140      |   10
> 2143      |   10
> 2166      |    4
```

Answer (score -1):

So in your application.py you should have this code in order to get the right database, this should be somewhere up in the file, so that it can be accessed by all of your functions.

```py
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Then somewhere bellow in the function that you want the time to have, you should have something like this

```py
timestamp = db.execute(text("SELECT timestamp FROM NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE").fetchall()#this will get you all of the timestamps
```

Now you have the timestamp from your table in your python, so you can easily do whatever you want to it, you could easily transfer it to datetime format and then just use the datetime.datetime.now() function and subtract it from each other, if you need anything else, feel free to comment down below.

Edit: So in order to loop through the IDs column, you would need something like this:

```
T1 = db.execute(text("SELECT object_ids FROM NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE")).fetchall()
for i in T1:
   
   timestamp = db.execute(text("SELECT timestamps FROM NAME_OF_YOUR_TABLE WHERE object_ids=:object_ids"), {'object_ids':i}).fetchone()
   print('Timestamp = ' + timestamp 'and id = ' + i)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. I actually need the total duration for every object_ids in the zone  as I will be displaying the waiting time of the queue on my dashboard and it will be refreshed automatically.

Comment: @gabgabgab93 I edited my code, so that it will get all of the timestamps, then you can just loop through them in python

Comment: Hi Oliver, I think what I actually need is to loop through every 'object_ids' and flag out the start and end timestamps in order to compute the time elapsed for each id. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, changed my answer again, would you give it a try now, please and let me now how it goes, thanks